how to get chart point from crossover
I want to get a chart point from crossover for place a label in pine script language.
I write a code that give crosses between a plot (sma) and price to make a label but I don't know how to give chart point to label function. please help me.
l don't have any idea fo this.

store chart.point.now() value when crossover condition is true
